# ThreeJS Getting Started code gives console error

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to attempt to learn Three.js from their getting started guide: http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene and I have the code as exactly from the site. I am using the latest code from their site, as for the library. The error in the console is as follows:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mergeVertices'`

I am not really too sure on what the issue is

Here is the code that is from the site that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Three JS App</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        // To be able to view anything with Three.js we need a scene, a camera, and a renderer
        //      -> To render the scene with the camera
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var geometry = THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame( render )

            cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };
        render();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more careful. Check your code.

Comment: well besides I am using 10 for the parameters in the Box Geometry.. I will take a another look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what @WestLangley suggested, I needed to review my code. I was missing a `new` in geometry declaration, and my `renderer.setSize` call needed 2 params instead of 1 (I was using a ratio) and the final `var render = function....` I needed to take out the second `render`

Sometimes it is good to have a second pair of eyes.. Thanks again @WestLangley